# dotdotdot add ellipsis even when not truncated

Tags: dotdotdot

I use dotdotdot to truncate text in height specified box

```
<div class="product-description dotdotdot" style="word-wrap: break-word;">
    <div class="product-description-icon">
        <span>
            <img src="product_gloves.png" alt="Gloves">
        </span>
    </div>
    <h4>Gloves</h4>
    <p>Some gloves text...</p>
</div>
```

jQuery :

```
$(".product-description.dotdotdot").dotdotdot({
    watch: true
});
```

My `product-description dotdotdot` have a min-height of 100px, and the text have the ellipsis at the end, but the text is not truncated and there is still a lot of free space.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a jquery plugin for ellipses and not just using CSS?  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have downloaded dotdotdot and followed the README.md and it is working fine (except on `$(window).resize`).

You might need to provide more context with your question:

- Are you including all the necessary `.js` files in the `<head>` of your markup and in the right order?
- Is your jQuery wrapped in a `$(document).ready(function() {` **your script** `});`

I haven't looked in depth at the dotdotdot script yet. Mine is firing using exactly this script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".wrapper").dotdotdot({
        // configuration goes here
    });
});
```

At a glance I am wondering if your choice of class name `.dotdotdot` might be causing issues. Perhaps rename your class(es) to read `.product-description-wrapper` and run the script on that class.

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

I would use a **pure CSS3** approach instead of jQuery.

Here are two of my favorite **SASS** mixins to achieve both word-wrapping or an ellipsis;

```
@mixin word-wrap() {
  word-break:     break-word;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens:    auto;
  hyphens:         auto;
}

@mixin ellipsis() {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```